# Blender Non-Planar geometry meaning

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have some question about Non-Planar geometry
 1. What is non planar geometry?
 2. Why this happens after rendering?

**Why did I get this line in the middle and the shading is different.**

[image]

Comment: Please clarify "*Why this happens after rendering?*" **What** is happening after the render?

Comment: @Leander I've added a picture of that.